# Permutations with a limited length in Julia

Tags: permutation, julia

In Python, you can use `itertools` to generate permutations like so:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations("ABC", 2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')]
```

Julia has a similar `permutations` function, but it only accepts one argument. What is the best way to emulate the second argument in the Python function?

Comment: I added an issue requesting this functionality at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12863.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subsets` from [Iterators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) with `k=2` should get you every subset of size 2, then you could take every permutation of the subset.